# Why can't i submit form to cloud database from my deployed flask web app

Tags: python, flask, registration, mysql-connector

when try to submit registration data to mysql database from planetscale i get the following on the web-browser " Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

when i checked the render (hosting provider) event log i am having this "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)."

i am wondering why it has to be Local MYSQL when i am using planet scale and i was giving an aws db which is cloud

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
  host= os.getenv("HOST"),
  user=os.getenv("USERNAME"),
  passwd= os.getenv("PASSWORD"),
  db= os.getenv("DATABASE"),
  autocommit = True,
  ssl_mode = "VERIFY_IDENTITY",
  ssl      = {
    "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
  }
)
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO register(first_name, middle_name, last_name,username, email, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (first_name, middle_name, last_name,username, email, password))

        #commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #close connection
        cur.close()
```